# node.js - require a file, then use a function without explicitly using the required file as a namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a very simple question. Let's say the file `test.js` has the following contents:

`exports.epsilon = function () {return []}`

I then require the file in node with `var t = require("./test")`.
I want to use the function `epsilon` directly, i.e. `epsilon()`, without explicitly setting the namespace via `t.epsilon()`.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a variable, like `t`, it's not a namespace, and it doesn't really matter, but if you just have to have everything on one line, you can use `var t = require("./test").epsilon()` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason you can't immediately assign the property of the module to a variable:

```
var epsilon = require("./test").epsilon;

epsilon(); // to call it
```

So long as the `epsilon` function does not expect `this` to be the `exports` object, which would be an odd design choice for a module, this will work perfectly.

Comment: Yes, well I was wondering if I can avoid this explicit assignment as in OCaml's module system, where I can just "use" a file (same as "require") and then have all of the used file's functions in the new file's namespace.